# lagging in switch between visible element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap

I use ScrollMagic in combination with GSAP to achieve animation like in [nytimes](http://nytimes.com/interactive/2016/08/02/business/dealbook/this-is-your-life-private-equity.html) website. My HTML code looks like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="scenes-wrapper">
        <div class="scenes active" id="scene-1"><!-- 3 to 5 big images inside --></div>
        <div class="scenes" id="scene-2"><!-- 3 to 4 big images inside --></div>
        <div class="scenes" id="scene-3"><!-- 3 to 4 big images inside --></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`.scenes` is hidden (`display:none`) by default execpt with `.active` class. for example my scrollbar is on `#scene-1` and then I scroll to the `#scene-2` section, that will cause scene 1 loose active class, and scene 2 now has active class. the problem is, the transition is not smooth, when hitting `.scenes` the scrollbar jumping down, but if i scrollback to up and scrolling down once more, the animation become smooth.

what causing this? I already tried changing `display` to `visibility` and `opacity`, but the result is the same. also, I use preload to preload images.

complete app can be found [here](http://148.251.76.241/bvl/index.sm.html)

Comment: Well I'm sure you understand your problem because you know your code and everything, but it would be appreciated if you could make a jsfiddle example so we can replicate the problem and work a solution on a dynamic example since this is the real issue here. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks @Kiwad I put the complete app here http://148.251.76.241/bvl/index.sm.html